# Is finding/using the MGF an appropriate strategy for this problem?

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Problem statement: Suppose we have a random sample $\{X_i:1\le i\le10\}$ from a normal distribution with mean $\mu=20$ and variance $\sigma^2=100$. Find the probability,
$$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^6X_i>X_7+2X_8+2X_9+X_{10}+16\right)$$
My initial thoughts: For any $X_i$, we know the MGF is $M_{X_i}(t)=20t+50t^2$. I defined a new random variable $Y$ denoted by the linear combination in which every term in the inequality is on one side, i.e.
$$Y=X_1+\cdots+X_6-X_7\cdots-X_{10}-16$$
so that now the problem is finding $P(Y>0)$. I find that the MGF of $Y$ is
$$M_Y(t)=e^{-16t}\left(20t+50t^2\right)^6\left(-20t+50t^2\right)^2\left(-40t+200t^2\right)^2$$
Is this making the problem more difficult than it needs to be? I don't think this looks like the MGF of a distribution I might be familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one can use the mgf to show that if $X_i$ are independent normal, then $\sum a_iX_i$ is normal.   But that is a basic result, so I would just **use it**. Let 
$$W=\sum_1^6 X_i-X_7-2X_8-2X_9-X_{10}-16.$$  Then $W$ has normal distribution. 
Compute the mean and variance of $W$. You should get mean $-16$ and variance $1600$, and now it's almost over.

Comment: I must have forgotten about that fact. Thanks for the reminder. On a side note, this would mean the MGF of $Y$ is $-16t+800t^2$, but that's clearly not the same as what I would get if were to expand the expression in my original question, so either I made a mistake in the computation of the MGF or I'm missing something...

Comment: There are mistakes in the mgf calculation. The first term $\exp(-16t)$ is OK. The other terms should  be exponentials, since the normal has mgf $\exp(\mu t+(\sigma^2/2)t^2)$.  Remember that if $g(t)$ is the mgf of $X$ then $g(at)$ is the mgf of $aX$. If you do it right you will get something that simplifies to $\exp(-16t +800t^2)$. If you run into trouble I can add the calculation as a remark.

Comment: Oh right, I completely forgot about the exponential function! Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You are welcome. If I do not get another message, I will assume that the mgf calculation went fine. The right thing to do is to prove  (as has probably been done in your book/course) that a linear combination of independent normals is normal, and not try to reprove it in particular cases whenever one meets a new problem.